# Not able to use dotenv

Tags: java, dotenv

While following a tutorial, when I write the following:
Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.configure().directory("/assets").filename("env").load()

I get the error ' cannot resolve symbol Dotenv.
I have tried npm install dotenv etc. in command prompt, clean, rebuild etc. all in vain. Much frustrated..any help most welcome!

Comment: I am using java

Comment: You need to use the `dotenv` available libraries. Maybe it is not a built-in function I guess read this article for more details https://dzone.com/articles/dotenv-for-java-and-the-jvm

Comment: Thanks both. Thanks Venkatesh..I got the right dependency from the article and that solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem got resolved when I added the following dependency in build gradle:

implementation 'io.github.cdimascio:java-dotenv:5.2.2'